# Repeated Flood Fill Optimization

Tags: algorithm

I'm using a grid based system with crossable and non-crossable squares with A* for finding paths, and with flood fill to see if it's possible to find a path (to see if two areas are connected).

My problem is that new uncrossable areas could be introduced quite frequently (up to 16 times a second) and the grid is fairly large (about 500 by 500) so even the O(mn) flood fill solution would take a fairly long amount of time. I have looked at different implementations of floodfill and couldn't find anything similar to what I want.

So my question is that is there any way to optimize repeated flood fill calls based on the previous grid and with a list of new uncrossable areas (which will always be rectangular)?

Comment: I'm sorry if I wasn't clear enough; I didn't want to overload anyone with too much information and this is the first time I've asked a question (before I could always find someone else asking it). The grid size is fixed, there are nxm squares, you move horizontally and vertically, and updates only mark all squares as non-crossable (or crossable).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Start by partitioning the crossable squares into connected components with a flood fill algorithm.

When you mark a region as non-crossable, consider the set S  of all the crossable squares outside the region adjacent to a previously crossable square in the region. For each component C which has at least two members in S, use flood fill to check if C has been disconnected.

When you mark a region as crossable, consider the set S  of all the crossable squares outside the region adjacent to a square in the region.Join all the components with a member in S.

Comment: Thanks, this is great! One more question: when non-crossable areas are sparse, is there anything else that can be done, because there will only really be one huge area to go through?